# Getting the error "nil:NilClass (No MethodError)"

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

***Please find the part of a code:***

```
button = Login_form.button_with(:name => 'Submit')
loggedin_page = Login_form.submit(button)


bizz_hierarchy_form=loggedin_page.form('login_showSplashForm')
button = bizz_hierarchy_form.button_with(:name => 'btnHome')  #error raised here
# buyer_page = bizz_hierarchy_form.submit(button)
# print buyer_page.title
```

***Error***

```
D:\Ruby script>ruby Test.rb
mechanize.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined method `button_with' for nil:NilClass (No
MethodError)

D:\Ruby script>
```

***html***

```
<td>
<input type="submit" name="btnHome" value="Homepage" class="btnBig"><input type="hidden" name="_synchToken_hom" value="1139cc8dd7d906f1"/>
</td>
```

Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: The form is missing. You're going to need to show an url for help with this one.

Comment: @pguardiario i have managed it anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `form('login_showSplashForm')` finds nothing, try to use `form_with` or maybe `forms.first`

Comment: still the same error. And the error is coming with the `button` line.

Comment: ofcourse it will come from `button` line b/c it tries to call a `button_with` methon on a `bizz_hierarchy_form` object **which is NULL**; check your HTML for correct classes, or, maybe there are no forms at all?

Comment: without form is it possible to click the button? Yes I just checked that before going the `page` there is a intermediate page having form `submit form` after that `login_showSplashForm` will come. But how to go from that intermediate page to `login_showSplashForm` page?